# How do I add custom fields into the Brands page in admin back office Prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, hook, custom-fields

I'm trying to add a custom field into the Brands page in the admin back office.

Before this, I successfully added a custom dropdown box in the Category page in the admin back office with `hookActionCategoryFormBuilderModifier` and used `hookActionAfterCreateCategoryFormHandler` and `hookActionAfterUpdateCategoryFormHandler` to handle the form's update and create logic.

However, when I try to do the same with in the Brand page (`hookActionBrandFormBuilderModifier`) nothing happens. Is there another way to do this? I can't seem to find another hook related to Brands so any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use:

`hookActionManufacturerFormBuilderModifier`.

Replace `Brand` with the `Manufacturer` as in reality brands, are just manufacturers and wording have changed but not a class name for example.